# how to nested loop with many state variables into a table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

How to list many variables into a table, 
like for loop i,j,k

```
this.state = {

            materials: ['m1', 'm2'],
            quantity: ['2', '4'],
            unitPrice : ['12', '15'],
            detailtotal: ['0', '1'],
        };
```

and listing:

```
<Table>
    <thead>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>total</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {this.state.materials.map( obj => {return(
        <tr>
            <td >{obj.materials}</td>
            <td>{obj.quantity}</td>
            <td>{obj.unitPrice}</td>
            <td>{obj.detailtotal}</td>
        </tr>
    )})}
    </tbody>
</Table>
```

the expected result as

material qty unitprice total
_____________________________
m1       2   12        0
m2       4   15        1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you will see that the Array.prototype.map() method gives you an index for the current element. So all you have to do is: (but this assumes that the data in all the arrays is in the same order)

```
{this.state.materials.map((obj, index) => (
    <tr>
        <td >{obj.materials[index]}</td>
        <td>{obj.quantity[index]}</td>
        <td>{obj.unitPrice[index]}</td>
        <td>{obj.detailtotal[index]}</td>
    </tr>
))}
```

A better approach would be to save the associated data together in a single object like so:

```
this.state = {
  materials: [
    {
      material: 'm1',
      quantity: 2,
      unitPrice: 12,
      total: 0
    },
    {
      material: 'm2',
      quantity: 4,
      unitPrice: 15,
      total: 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can call them like this:

```
    {this.state.materials.map(obj => (
        <tr>
            <td >{obj.material}</td>
            <td>{obj.quantity}</td>
            <td>{obj.unitPrice}</td>
            <td>{obj.total}</td>
        </tr>
    ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your state to this array and use in your HTML

```
let state = {

            materials: ['m1', 'm2'],
            quantity: ['2', '4'],
            unitPrice : ['12', '15'],
            detailtotal: ['0', '1'],
   };

    values =    Object.values(state);
    result = [];
    for(i =0; i < values[0].length; i++){
       item = { materials: values[0][i], quantity: values[1][i], unitPrice: values[2][i], detailtotal: values[3][i]}
       result.push(item);
    }

    console.log(result)
```

```js
let state = {
       materials: ['m1', 'm2'],
       quantity: ['2', '4'],
       unitPrice : ['12', '15'],
       detailtotal: ['0', '1'],
};
        
values =    Object.values(state);
result = [];

for(i =0; i < values[0].length; i++){
   item = { materials: values[0][i], quantity: values[1][i], unitPrice: values[2][i], detailtotal: values[3][i]}
       result.push(item);
}
    
console.log(result)
```